# How to write this as a function in Matlab? (vectors)

Tags: matlab

I have a vector A = (A1, A2, A3) which is orthogonal to another unit vector, v = (v1,v2,v3), whose first coordinate is 0. I have come up with the following:

```
v2 = [0 A(2) -A(3)];
v3 = [0 -A(2) A(3)];
v2 = v2/norm(v2)
v3 = v3/norm(v3)
```

But if I want to write/code it as a function instead where A is the input value, how do I do that?

I understand that functions can be written as function[v2,v3] = Name(A3,A2) but how do I do it on above if the function is not given?

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question, so Please, give a numeric application ! (an example in numbers of A and the resulting V), may be i can help you.

Comment: Can you also specify precisely what the function inputs and outputs should be? Once you are able to articulate that, you may be able to figure this question out yourself using MATLAB's function documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Answer (score 0):

As I correct understand your question, you want create a function which will give you second and third coordinates of vector orthogonaling the firs vector.
So, as you know when vectors A тв B are orthogonaling, the scalar (А,В)=0
so we can write the function to using this property

```
function [v2,v3] = orthogonal_to(A2,A3)
% (A*v) = 0 
%0 =0*0 + v2 * A2 + v3 * A3
% v2 * A2 = - 1 * (v3 * A3)
% we have infinity number of vectors, so let v3 = 1 (or any other number)
v3 = 1;
v2 = ( -1 * (v3 * A3) ) / A2;
end
```

save this function like orthogonal_to.m
then call it in matlab command window like `[v2,v3] = orthogonal_to(1,2)`